# jquery css left property doesn't work with Vue 2

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I have a little problem with Jquery and VueJS 2. I have the following css

```
 .slider{
       position: relative;
       transition: all .2s;
    }
```

and the following JavaScript

```
...
    methods:{
        move: function(){
            $('.slider').css('left', -100%/3 + '%');
        }
    }
...
```

But nothing's working. As you may assume, what I want is to edit the left property of the slider element by clicking another element in the same component. I don't know if this is because of Vue or not. I have used the same trick in previous projects without Vue, so... I hope you can help me

Comment: what this `left` is?  `left margin`,`left padding`,`left arrow`,`left align`? what among these. because only `left` doesn't make sense

Comment: It's just `left`. For exmaple, when you have an element with `position : relative` or `position: absolute` you can use `left`, `top`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with Vue here, Just remove the `%`,

```
...
    methods:{
        move: function(){
            $('.slider').css('left', -100/3 + '%');
        }
    }
...
```

Good luck.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, That char was not in the code. It was a mistake, really sorry